# Error 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected1 when trying to addChild

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to AS3, trying to add this VectorFile which contain boxes of result into the as file(sresultnologin). But it is displaying Error 1136 Incorrect number of arguments. Expected1 when trying to addChild,on this line `var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest();`.
Wondering what is this error, and how can i fix it. Thanks for your time.

As3(sresultnologin)

```
package com.clark

{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;




       public class sresultnologin extends MovieClip {

public var s1:Searchreult = new Searchreult ();

               public function sresultnologin(){
                  // init



            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);
         function onadded (event:Event):void{



            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);
         }

var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest();
                 addChild (s3);


            s1.SRhome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTol);
            s1.ARsearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGosearch);



           }
               // private methods

        private function fl_ClickToGoTol(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:Account = new Account ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);

        }
        private function fl_ClickToGosearch(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:searchVO1 = new searchVO1 ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);


       }

}
}
```

SearchVectorTest

```
package  com.clark
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {


        public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1>) 
        {
            super();



                for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) 
            {
                trace(test[j].nobed);
                trace(test[j].zip);
                trace(test[j].Location);
                trace(test[j].price);


        }



            var currentY:int = 270;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing5 = new Listing5();

                Bolder.x=80;

                var bf:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

                bf3.width = 100;
                bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                bf.width = 100;
                bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf1.width = 100;
                bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.width = 100;
                bf1.y= bf.height+5;



                bf.text = test[k].nobed;
                bf1.text = test[k].zip;
                bf2.text = test[k].Location;
                bf3.text = test[k].price;

                bf1.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5

                bf3.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5


                bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5
                bf.y = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.15
                Bolder.addChild(bf);
                Bolder.addChild(bf1);
                Bolder.addChild(bf2);
                Bolder.addChild(bf3);



                Bolder.y = currentY;


                addChild(Bolder);
                currentY += Bolder.height + 35;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: May be it is because of extra space before the brace?

Answer (score 1):

Your `SearchVectorTest` constructor expects an argument, as stated in the line `public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1>)`, and you are attempting to pass 0 arguments into that constructor. Also you can't pass null in there, as you are requesting vector's length in the constructor. You need to either give it a valid vector at once, or call `new SearchVectorTest(new Vector.<searchVO1>())` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry that i am very new to AS3, and i really don't know much, just learning at the moment. Do i add the valid Vector into the () from var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest();? But the SearchVectorTest file doesn't just contains Vectors, it contains Textfields and the box that the text sits in etc

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code, Constructor of **SearchVectorTest** class has an argument of type Vector. So when creating instance you need to pass an argument of type vector to that constructor, like
 `var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(anyVectorObject);`

Otherwise make that argument as default argument, say change your constructor code to

```
public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1> = null)
```

Hope it helps